# video recording multiple instances of chrome driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, xvfb

I use xvfb to open up a display and run selenium tests in parallel using chromedriver. so you can have multiple chromedrivers running at a time. how can I add video recording so that i can record each session separately? Is there a plugin I can use to add video recording for each selenium session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ffmpeg` or `avconv` (a fork of ffmpeg) for it.

```
avconv \
-f x11grab \         # input for grabbing from X11
-r 15 \              # Frame rate
-s 400x300 \         # Size and width of area to capture
-i :0.0 \            # The display number you created with xvfb
-vcodec libx264 \    # the video codec
/tmp/output-file.mp4
```